# Haskell lens : view doesn't reference like over and set?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

First time using `lens`. `set` and `over` went easy enough and I thought it would be simple with `view`: Use the same scheme to reference the inner part, but don't supply a new value or function.  But Noooo. `tst3 below gives the error below the code`. Anyone know what's going on?

```
-- Testing lenses
tst1 = set (inner . ix 0 . w) 9 outer
tst2 = over (inner . ix 0 . w) (+2) outer
tst3 = view (inner . ix 0 . w) outer       -- this line errors out

    * No instance for (Monoid Int) arising from a use of `ix'
    * In the first argument of `(.)', namely `ix 0'
      In the second argument of `(.)', namely `ix 0 . w'
      In the first argument of `view', namely `(inner . ix 0 . w)'
```

Here is some pared down code illustrating.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Control.Lens

data Inner = Inner
    {  _w :: Int
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

data Outer = Outer
    { _inner :: [Inner]
    } deriving Show

outer = Outer
    [
    Inner 0,
    Inner 1,
    Inner 2
    ]

makeLenses ''Inner
makeLenses ''Outer

tst1 = set (inner.ix 0.w) 999 outer
tst2 = over (inner.ix 0.w) (+77) outer
tst3 = view (inner.ix 0.w) outer        -- this errors out
```

I've read up on `view` and the simple examples look like mine, as in,

```
>>> let atom = Atom { _element = "C", _point = Point { _x = 1.0, _y = 2.0 } }
>>> view (point . x) atom
1.0
```

though I haven't found an example that indexes an inner structure with ix.

Comment: `outer [inner]` is not a real data type. Please include the actual type definitions needed to reproduce.

Comment: Look at the "more restricted signatures" in [the documentation for `view`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html#v:view). I suspect your "lens" is actually a fold or traversal or something. As amalloy said, please post a fully reproducible example, so that we can see exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `ix 0` is a traversal, not a lens, so instead of focusing on **the** 0th element, it focuses on the collection of **all** elements that are the 0th element.  Why does it do this?  Well, assuming `_inner` is a list of type `[Inner]`, *usually* there's only one element that is the 0th element, but sometimes (if the list is empty), there are **no** elements that are the 0th element.  Having `ix 0` be a traversal accounts for this possibility.

Since `ix 0` is a traversal, it "poisons" the whole optic `inner . ix 0 . w`.  Even if `inner` and `w` are lenses, the composition with `ix 0` is "only" a traversal.

Now, there's no problem with "setting" or "overing" with a traversal.  If there's no 0th element, the operation just doesn't do anything.  On the other hand, there *is* a bit of a problem with *viewing* such a traversal.  If you expect to get an element, you might not get one.

The error message arises because `view` tries to handle traversals by assuming the result is a `Monoid`.  This allows it to combine zero, one, or multiple results from the traversal into a single return value of the same type.  This functionality is kind of esoteric, which makes the error message pretty confusing, but you get used to seeing it.

There are several things you can do.  You can replace `view` with a special view operators.  The usual view operator `^.` is similar to `view`, so it generates the same error message:

```
-- parentheses are optional here, but included for clarity
tst4 = outer ^. (inner . ix 0 . w)
```

But the operators `^..`, `^?` and `^?!` will all type check:

```
tst5 = outer ^.. (inner . ix 0 . w)
tst6 = outer ^? (inner . ix 0 . w)
tst7 = outer ^?! (inner . ix 0 . w)
```

The first `(^..)` returns all (zero or more) results of the traversal as a list.  The second `(^?)` returns the first result as a `Maybe`, using `Nothing` to indicate there were no results.  The last `(^?!)` returns the first result directly, generating an error if there are zero results (like using `head` on an empty list).

Comment: Thanks so much. I thought it was a ```traversal not a lens``` kind of issue but don't have the chops yet to go wade through it all. Yours and @Ben's answer give me some guidance over raw documentation.

Comment: @user49011 Yeah, the documentation is detailed and clear, but there are so many inter-linking concepts that it's still *really* hard to make use of the docs until you're basically comfortable with a fairly large chunk of the lens ecosystem. You need to learn from tutorials, questions like this, and trial and error, *then* the docs become useful. That's even more so of the error messages you get from lenses, unfortunately. This `Monoid` error makes perfect sense *when you already know how it works*. It's of no use trying to *figure out* how it works.

Comment: The operators all have normal function names too; switching to an operator does nothing to resolve the issue, it's just a different style; you can use whichever you prefer. For example where `^.` corresponds to `view`, `^?` corresponds to `preview`, and `^..` corresponds to `toListOf`. I like the operator style myself, since the operators provide "break points" to avoid some parentheses (it also puts the arguments in an order that is more familiar to OO programmers, which appeals to some), but the prefix style is more convenient when writing functions rather than fully applied usage.

Answer (score 4):

[`ix 0` doesn't produce a lens, but a traversal.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#v:ix)<sup>1</sup>

Informally, a lens is a "path" that will definitively reach a single value (if you follow it within a hypothetical larger value). A traversal is a path to **zero or more** values. You can `set` or `view` the single target of a lens. And you can `set` the zero or more targets of a traversal (this simply updates all of them that are present, which is a no-op if there are zero present). But `view`ing the targets of a traversal is less straightforward.

If `view` simply took a traversal, and an outer structure, and gave you the target value, then it would have a problem. If there are multiple targets, how should it decide which to return? And if there are zero targets, it can't return anything; it would have to be partial. What it needs is a way of condensing zero-or-more values into a single value, so it can return that. And the `Monoid` class provides exactly the facilities to do that; `mempty` for if there aren't any targets at all, and `<>` to condense multiple values to a single one. So `view` with a traversal<sup>2</sup> actually requires a `Monoid` constraint on the returned type, and that's why you're getting the complaint about `` No instance for (Monoid Int) arising from a use of `ix' ``.

And in case it isn't clear, you can often compose (with `.`) different types of optics (the general term for "lens-ish things", including lenses, traversals, and several others). But the result has the capabilities of the *least* capable of the two inputs. So even though your `inner` and `w` are full lenses, composing them with a traversal produced by `ix` results in a traversal, not a lens.

But in this case you know that you're using `ix`. The specific kind of traversals `ix` makes end up having zero **or one** target, rather than the zero *or more* targets that traversals have in general. So you could use [`preview` instead of `view`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:preview); for a traversal it will produce a `Maybe` containing `Just` the first target of the traversal, or `Nothing` if there weren't any. A `Maybe` is exactly what the type system deems appropriate here, since `ix` can't guarantee there will *be* a target value, but there won't be more than one.

In my experience, when I try to `view` something and get this `Monoid` instance error, it almost always means I have an optic that can't guarantee a result and I should actually be using `preview` to get a `Maybe`.

Simple example:

```
λ view (ix 1) [True, False]

<interactive>:16:7: error:
    • No instance for (Monoid Bool) arising from a use of ‘ix’
    • In the first argument of ‘view’, namely ‘(ix 1)’
      In the expression: view (ix 1) [True, False]
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = view (ix 1) [True, False]

λ preview (ix 1) [True, False]
Just False
it :: Maybe Bool

λ preview (ix 1) [True]
Nothing
it :: Maybe Bool
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `ix` can't return lenses, because it's supposed to take an index and then represent a "path" into **any** indexable structure (that can be indexed by the type of index it was given, at least). In `ix 0`, `ix` hasn't seen the particular structure you're going to use it on yet, so there's no way it can guarantee there is a value at that index; you could even use `let i = ix 0` and then use `i` multiple times to peek into different structures!

---

<sup>2</sup> More technically, `view` is supported by traversals because it's supported by folds, and all traversals are folds. A fold knows how to *access* zero-or-more targets, but unlike a traversal it isn't a "path"; it just accesses the values with no knowledge about their context in the structure (other than a canonical order).

There's a handy but confusing diagram on the main [hackage page for the `lens` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens), which attempts to describe how the major functionality is "inherited" by various flavours of optics. It's a little overwhelming... but less so than the full documentation scattered over many different modules.

You should be able to see that in the top right we have `Setter` providing `set` and `over`, which is inherited by `Traversal`. Whereas in the top left we have `view` with a `Monoid` constraint, that is inherited by `Traversal`. In the mid-left we have `Getter` having a version of `view` *without* the `Monoid` constraint, which is inherited by `Lens` but *not* by `Traversal`.